# Why does AJAX success function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't know why that success doesn't work. I even saw later someone having same code and it worked.

```
function doButtonUpdate(buttonNumber) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        url: '/Button/ShowOneButton',
        data: {
            "buttonNumber":buttonNumber
        },
        
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#" + buttonNumber).html(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing the log message? If not, it means the AJAX request wasn't successful, check the log for errors.

Comment: Yes, press F12 to open the dev tools, go to the console tab and if necessary, turn on `xhr`. Then click again and check the xhr.

Answer (score 1):

In the `dataType` parameter you specify `"json"`, which means this is the type of data you are expecting to receive from the server.

But since you are directly inserting received `data` into the HTML, I suspect you are not receiving a valid `json` response (maybe HTML or just plain text?). Hence the success callback is not executed. Try leaving out this parameter, which should then fall back to an "intelligent guess" for the received data type.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/